# How can I disable checksum feature in brasero?

Tags: brasero, md5sum

Is there any option in brasero to disable the checksum feature in brasero? It slows down the burning.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Go to Applications > Sound & Video > Brasero Disc Burner
2. Select Edit > Plugins
3. Disable these plugins:

   - File Checksum
   - Image Checksum

[Source](https://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2010/11/15/disable-annoying-creating-image-checksum-in-brasero-after-ubuntu-10-10-upgrade/)

Comment: @kv1dr you're welcome! I know how it feels like when you remove those little bumps.

Comment: I think the file checksum feature is quite useful, though. Brasero should only be a little bit clearer about how it's used. Having a file on the same DVD with the checksum of every file is, in my opinion, THE solution for always being able to check whether a DVD has become corrupt over time, and possibly to find out which file is affected.